# Get all elements of nested lists with recursion

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion

~ from [This Edabit Challenge](https://edabit.com/challenge/2nciiXZN4HCuNEmAi) ~

I need to get all the elements of nested lists and put them all in one list using recursion.
My code below prints out each element, but how do I save them all to one list and return them?

It has to be kept in the scope of the function. I can't add a global list and append all of them. It works technically, but it doesn't work for the challenge I'm trying to pass.

I printed the values out (which is var x in the code) because that shows me that I'm getting close (I think). I just need a way to return the values back to my function and have it append it to the list that I will eventually return.

**Examples:** 
`flatten([[[[[["direction"], [372], ["one"], [[[[[["Era"]]]], "Sruth", 3337]]], "First"]]]]) ➞ ["direction", 372, "one", "Era", "Sruth", 3337, "First"]`

`flatten([[4666], [5394], [466], [[["Saskia", [[[[["DXTD"]], "Lexi"]]]]]]]) ➞ [4666, 5394, 466, "Saskia", "DXTD", "Lexi"]`

Code:

```
    def flatten(arr):   
        
        res = [] 
        if isinstance(arr, list):
            for i in arr:
                res.append(flatten(i))
        else:
            return arr
        if isinstance(res, list):
            for i in res:
                x = flatten(i)
                if x:
                    print(x)
            
    
    
    x = flatten([[[[[["direction"], [372], ["one"], [[[[[["Era"]]]], "Sruth", 3337]]], "First"]]]])
    print(main)
```

outputs :

```
    direction
    372
    one
    Era
    Sruth
    3337
    First
    []
```

The output above shows that my code goes through every non-list value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to offer two solutions: the first uses recursion and the second uses a queue.

## First solution

```py
def flatten_helper(nested):
    for e in nested:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            yield from flatten_helper(e)
        else:
            yield e
            
def flatten(nested):
    return list(flatten_helper(nested))
```

The `flatten_helper` function is a generator, which generates a list of elements that are not a list. If an element is a list, we call `flatten_helper` again until we get non-list elements.

## Second solution

```py
import collections

def flatten(nested):
    queue = collections.deque(nested)
    out = []
    while queue:
        e = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(e, list):
            queue.extendleft(reversed(e))
        else:
            out.append(e)
    return out
```

In this solution, we loop through the nested list. If the element is a list, we place each sub element into a queue for later processing. If the element is not a list, we append it to `out`.

Comment: Interesting, I've never used `extendleft` and I would've had to look it up (or test it) to find out in which order the values get appended. Why not use a stack (i.e., list), though? Seems more usual.

Comment: If you use a helper, you might want to make the helper append to a list created in the main function. Avoids the quadratic runtime that you currently have there.

Comment: @KellyBundy: if queue is `[1,2,3]`, and e is `[4,5,6]`, then `queue.extendleft(reversed(e)) --> [4,5,6,1,2,3]`. I am using a queue because I want to preserve the order of the elements.

Comment: @KellyBundy: interesting suggestion regarding the helper. Would you mind post that as an answer so I can learn?

Comment: The stack can preserve the order as well. Actually, since you extend/pop only on the left you really rather *are* using a stack, just a reversed one. Added an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Variations of Hai Vu's solutions...

**Their first solution** uses nested generators, meaning every value gets yielded through that stack of generators. If the structure is deeply nested, this can make the solution take *quadratic* instead of linear time overall. An alternative is to create a local list in the main function and have the helper function fill it. I prefer using a nested function for that, so I don't have to pass the list around and don't expose the helper function to the outside.

```
def flatten(nested):
    flat = []
    def helper(nested):
        for e in nested:
            if isinstance(e, list):
                helper(e)
            else:
                flat.append(e)
    helper(nested)
    return flat
```

[Benchmark](https://tio.run/##jVFLawIxEL7nV8xFzIqIVgoieBd672WREN1JDSSzIZs97K/f5oFa7VI6p2Qy32vihnBtabtzfhwbVKCMDAFJXNE49JywC9hUewaxVOsBQROUbmmm0gp0p6kLki7IcQlGd6F6vKcaNJoGlG/tqwZW90E0HU7B8KnHktGj1OKzfzboMfSesjqfDlKxDP5AY4aXcHEeDlCf8i0NTa3gzzX8dxWpfmefzn@ztpLOITU3wLO3n@HTMGPlIebJu/CSvpDv1uuYP7kXyf2jWRTvkLqcTozl3wraog6grWt9iCoOo0BiUT1dElFdvmJZtnqCBWwLY0JGPquJFxg30p4buc/Qm/klUG/P6A@bqgRxXlPg89n76k2B7WAOM@CZawEb3EZAgq@EIGlRiGocvwE) with 800 integers at depth 800:

```
26.03 ms  Hai_Vu
 0.25 ms  Kelly
25.62 ms  Hai_Vu
 0.24 ms  Kelly
26.07 ms  Hai_Vu
 0.24 ms  Kelly
```

**Their second solution** uses a "queue" (but really treats it like a "reversed" stack, extending/popping only on the left). I think an ordinary stack (using a list) is more natural and simpler:

```
def flatten(nested):
    stack = [nested]
    out = []
    while stack:
        e = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(e, list):
            stack += reversed(e)
        else:
            out.append(e)
    return out
```

Comment: Both solutions work well. It is a great learning experience. Thank you, Kelly.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a list to flatten, and append to it at each step:

```
def flatten(arr, list_):
    if isinstance(arr, list):
        for i in arr:
            flatten(i, list_)
    else:
        list_.append(arr)


test = [['a'], 'b']
output = []
flatten(test, output)
output

['a', 'b']
```

EDIT: If you want specifically to return the list, use

```
def flatten(arr, list_=None):
    if list_ is None:
        list_ = []
    if isinstance(arr, list):
        for i in arr:
            flatten(i, list_)
    else:
        list_.append(arr)
    return list_
```

Comment: Try this `[['a'], ('b','a')]`.

Comment: OP said nested lists, not nested lists and tuples. My code can easily be adapted to that case.

Comment: you code doesn't work, I don't know who upvoted it.

Comment: like I know you can add a global list, append all values, then pass that list. But it doesn't work if that function gets called again. So it has to be in the scope of the function

Comment: It works fine. When you call the function again, you instantiate a new list first.

Comment: If you insist on it returning the value instead of processing it from outside, you can define it like

`def flatten(arr, list_=None):`, call `if list_ is None: list_ = []` inside the function, and return list_ at the end.

Comment: Hi! Nice one! What about removing the whole `None`-check block and set the default value as `..., list_=[]):`?

Comment: Because lists are mutable. The default value of list would change when the function was run, and then the results on a second run would be different unless you set list back to `[]`. In general, mutable objects that are being changed shouldn't be default values.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility... more on the same wavelength of Hai Vu 1st solution:

```
def flatter(lst):
    output = []
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            output.extend(flatter(i))
        else:
            output.append(i)
    return output
```